Criticisms of the Dedekind's definition of infinite sets for violating Euclid's Common Notion 5
Dedekind's definition of the infinite set says in its essence that part may be equal to the whole contradicting Euclid's Common Notion 5 stating that "the whole is greater than the part."
Dedekind's Definition 64 is on page 31 of this pdf:


Definition. A system $\mathbf{S}$ is said to be infinite when it is similar to a proper part of itself; in the contrary case
$\mathbf{S}$ is said to be a finite system.


I remember reading that Dedekind's definition was criticized for violating Euclid's Common Notion but I could not find where I read it.
Can anybody suggest a source where I can find such a discussion?

Not sure if this addresses your specific question, but historical interactions between Euclid's part-whole principle and properties of infinite sets are reviewed by Mancosu in Measuring the Size of Infinite Collections.

"In the early 1820s, Bolzano... warned his readers not to conflate one property of an infinite set — that it can be put in one-to-one correspondence with a proper subset of itself — with a criterion of ‘size’." SEP, Infinity. Bolzano's argument for this was exactly the part-whole principle. Dedekind made Bolzano's observation into a definition in 1884 and by that time Cantor already dismissed the part-whole objection and made 1-1 correspondences into a criterion of 'size' (cardinality).

@Conifold Yes, I found the pdf here https://web.archive.org/web/20190217184605id_/http://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/06b0/9323dd53c4b5e363f49b2216b94bcb6d805b.pdf so far I skimmed it and it looks like he talks about subjects related to my question. Thanks

@zeynel, did you find anything specifically on Dedekind?  Cantor may have dismissed the part-whole principle but that does not mean that everybody followed his lead immediately.
